# Как передать параметр в функцию другого компонента Vue?

Tags: vue.js

нужно передать данные email в дочерний компонент

главный компонент :

```
<template>
 <checkPhone
      v-show="isModalVisible"
      @close="closeModal"/>
</template
<script>
 import checkPhone from "~/components/auth/checkPhone.vue"
data() {
      return { email:""}
}
 methods: {
  components: { checkPhone }
      signin() {
  axios.post('auth/signin', {
          user: {
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password,
}
}
</script>
```

дочерний:

```
<script>
 checkEmail() {
      axios.post('auth/signin/confirm', {
        user: {
          email:this.email,
          confirmation_code: this.confirmation_code
        }
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего ч/з `props`. А в дочернем определить массив props.

```
<checkMail :email="email" />
```

В дочернем добавить строчку `props`:

```
export default { props: ['email'] }
```

Comment: получаю ошибку  The data property "email" is already declared as a prop. Use prop default value instead.

found in

Comment: Duplicated key 'email'  vue/no-dupe-keys

Comment: Уберите из data дочернего компонента email.